# Ethernet Adapter Detected but the ethernet cable isn't

Tags: networking, ethernet

I recently bought a usb ethernet adapter as my laptop has no ethernet ports. The laptop detects the adapter, the driver is installed, but the ethenet cable isn't detected. The cable works fine for other laptops. the results of   `ethtool enx00e001103008` shows:

```
Settings for enx00e001103008:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

The link detected always shows 'no'.

The output for `lshw -c network`
 is:

```
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx00e001103008
       serial: 00:e0:01:10:30:08
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=dm9601 driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=half firmware=Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 Ether link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Update: 
I used the command `cd /var/log ; tail -f dmesg $(find . -name \*log)`
and there were no warnings or errors. After this using `ifconfig -a` gave me the following output:

```
anbox0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.250.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::b880:48ff:fe81:ab8e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ba:80:48:81:ab:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 496  bytes 47816 (47.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx00e001103008: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:01:10:30:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2505  bytes 179890 (179.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2505  bytes 179890 (179.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.54.62  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 192.168.55.255
        inet6 fe80::bb7b:44f4:84f1:5d11  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:cd:b6:00:4b:23  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7323  bytes 5071950 (5.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8581  bytes 1294698 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? What is the Product/Model/Rev number of the adapter? Are you connecting directly to the laptop or thru a USB hub?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 19.04 and the adapter is ICS Advent DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter,I am connecting it through the laptop's USB port.

Comment: I would start with: 1) unplug the adapter, 2) In a terminal window run `cd /var/log ; tail -f dmesg $(find . -name \*log)`, and 3) plug the adapter back in and watch for any errors/warnings. Also, provide the output of `ifconfig -a` after the cable is plugged in.

Comment: I didn't receive any errors but "link down" message is shown over and over again.

Comment: @user219077 Did you ever find the solution?